# I can send mail with shell but can't sent mail via view

Tags: python, django, python-2.6, django-1.6

I use this settings to send email:

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.xxxxxx.ir"
EMAIL_PORT = "25"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "xxxxx@xxx.ir"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxx"
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  = 'xxxxx@xxx.ir'
```

and in python shell:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('test', 'hello', 'xxxxx@xxx.ir', ['myEmail@gmail.com'])
```

And its successfully sent But when i use that two line code in view, i got this error:

```
gaierror at /userforget/
[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Please help me.

Update:

this is my view code:

```
def userforget(request):
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    send_mail('test', 'hello', 'xxxxxx@xxxx.ir', ['myEmail@gmail.com'])

    t = get_template('Finalauth/login.html')
    html = t.render(Context({"userbody" : "<p>Email sent.</p>"}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: if it's dev server ? or did you restart the server. ! It's hard to tell without your view code ..

Comment: No i didnt restart the server and i add the view code to post as update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the IP rather than the name for EMAIL_HOST and its worked and its probably DNS problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and find there is no error except

```
t = get_template('Finalauth/login.html')
```

I mean, maybe, send_email is OK, however get_template is nor correct.

Then, please check the file '**Finalauth/login.html**' and **import** for **get_template, Context and HttpResponse**.

Comment: Thanks but that part is ok and i test that.